# How to implement Asynchronous Inter Thread Communication in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, asynchronous-postback

I am developing one code in which I have one parent thread and one child thread.Now, my scenario is like mentioned below,

- Parent thread start the child thread
- after starting the child thread it continuous to work what it is doing.
- Now one time occurs that child thread want to call the method in the main thread
- then it call asynchronously the main thread with that method.

I also want to clarify that I know the concurrency package in java but it is doing synchronously i.e. main thread have to wait for the child thread till it complete the execution,but I want the main thread to do continuous work while child thread executing.

My implementation is like `SwingWorker` Thread in java

Comment: What does it mean "child thread want to call the method in the main thread" ?

Comment: I do not understand "Now one time occurs that child thread want to call the method in the main thread then it call asynchronously the main thread with that method."  Please clarify with an example or some pseudo code or something to help me understand your flow better.

Comment: It is like child thread transfer the execution to the parent thread again.

Comment: Can't.  One thread can not "call" another thread.  One thread can not "transfer execution" to another thread.  Those phrases don't mean anything.  One thread _can_ start another thread, and one thread can wait for another thread to terminate.  One thread can put a message (i.e., an object) in a queue, and another thread can take the message out of the queue and do something with it.  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get to "call a method in the main thread". The only thing you can do is implement a specific mechanism whereby the main thread, by its own initiative, executes a method on an object which was provided by the child thread.

The above roughly describes what the Swing's mechanism does: the "main" thread (in that case, the Event Dispatch Thread) dequeues objects from a global queue and, if the object's type is appropriate, invokes the `run` method on an associated instance of `Runnable`.

Main point: in Swing the EDT doesn't "continue to work what it is doing"; it specifically waits for other threads to tell it what to do via this mechanism and otherwise just blocks, doing nothing at all.

Comment: Yes,I want similar mechanism but I don't want that main thread will wait for the child

Comment: You are asking for the impossible, as explained in this answer.

Comment: In android ui thread is doing its work till the child thread transfer the message to it.So,how it was possible.

Comment: Please,give me some suggestion.How can I implement this.

Comment: No, on Android it's the same as on Swing. The "work" you refer to consists entirely of dequeuing from the event queue and reacting as appropriate to each dequeued object.